# Working on both master and branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have created a branch but it seems that it replaced the master. I cannot see the branch's files on my folder. Basically it seems that master and branch are same files, like a one line. However I want to create a branch and then I want to work on both the branch and the master.

Comment: This is how git works, when you checkout a branch it replaces the previous branch  on your file system. Perhaps someone has a nifty trick for you, but if you really want both branches on disk at the same time you can always just do another git clone command in a separate directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git checkout` to switch between your two branches.

Comment: Someone changes the file! So it pulls it from the .git folder.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in this comment.

Comment: I thought that it was supposed to crate a separate folder for the branch however now I understand what happens. I'm going to accept you answer but it wants me to wait few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a new branch you actually make a clone of master branch to work seperately. If you run "git branch" you can see all of your branches and the one with the asterisk is your current branch. So you can use "git checkout BRANCHNAME" to move through different branches and work independently.